# Veto a CDI bean if another of the same type is present

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi

Not sure if I'm thinking right about this, I'm looking[in CDI] for something similar to what we have in Spring - `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` - that allows you tell spring - create only if the bean specified is missing.

I've tried using extensions, looks like one can tap several events, and use those to VETO beans. One way might be to have `BeanManager` at this stage, and look for already present beans, and if it contains the one you're about to inject, VETO this one. BUT, this would only work when we HAVE LOOKED AT ALL the beans.

`AfterBeanDiscovery` looks suitable, however, before it is invoked, validation fails, complaining of multiple beans of the same type.

Would be great if I could get some help here.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is what we call in CDI an `Alternative`.  But I want to understand a bit better.  You have an interface `Interface1`.  You want to install an implementation of this interface if and only if there is no other implementation registered as a bean, correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't want this context to have multiple beans of the same kind as that would lead to that "ambiguous dependencies" thingy. I'd like to produce one only if there's no other bean of the same kind present already in the context. If there is, that producer shouldn't kick in.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting and *can* be solved using a CDI extension (almost as you describe, actually), see below for a naive, working, proof-of-concept implementation. It is naive because it does not handle e.g. producer methods/fields and may be missing more.

CDI extensions are really great and powerful, but can be rather technical, so let's discuss other alternatives first.

1. **Specialization:** Maybe it is enough for your use case to document explicitly that you provide the default implementation of `SomeService` through, say, `public class SomeServiceDefaultImpl` and in order to override it the developer should do:

   ```
   @Specializes
   public class SomeServiceSpecialImpl extends SomeServiceDefaultImpl {...}
   ```

   Also consider the alternatives, as mentioned in the comment from John Ament.
2. **Qualifiers:** If this service is used only in one place/a few places and only inside your code, you could qualify your `SomeServiceDefaultImpl` with a custom qualifier, say `@MyDefaultImpl`. Then inject an `Instance<SomeService>`, look for an unqualified instance first and, if that is not satisfied, look for the qualified - something along the lines of:

   ```
   private SomeService someService;

   @Inject
   void setSomeServiceInstance(Instance<SomeService> s) {
       // not tried, please adapt as needed
       if( s.isUnsatisfied() ) {
           someService = s.select(new MyDefaultImplAnnotation()).get();
       }
       else {
           someService = s.get();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Provide a default implementation that is `@Vetoed` so as to force the client of your code to provide an implementation. If the client wants to use the default, they can simply use a producer.

---

Having said the above, the implementation below is a proof of concept that:

- Requires the following annotation to be present on the default implementation:

  ```
  @Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD })
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Documented
  public @interface ConditionalOnMissingBean {
      Class<?> value();
  }
  ```

  The `value()` is required and denotes the bean type that is "defaulted". Your implementation can be smarter, i.e. detect the bean type from the actual default implementation, but, hey, that's only a proof of concept!
- Blatantly ignores producers!
- Is lightly tested, so there are probably evil corner cases, so BEWARE!

In addition to the code you need all the choreography of an extension (META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension, beans.xml).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AfterBeanDiscovery;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanAttributes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionTargetFactory;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessAnnotatedType;

public class ConditionalOnMissingBeanExtension implements Extension {

    private Map<Class<?>, AnnotatedType<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat) {
        AnnotatedType<?> annotatedType = pat.getAnnotatedType();
        ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation = annotatedType.getAnnotation(ConditionalOnMissingBean.class);
        if( annotation != null ) {
            map.put(annotation.value(), annotatedType);
            pat.veto();
        }
    }

    void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery abd, BeanManager beanManager) {
        map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> doesNotHaveBeanOfType(beanManager, e.getKey()))
            .map(e -> defineBean(beanManager, e.getValue()))
            .forEach(abd::addBean);
        map = null;
    }

    private boolean doesNotHaveBeanOfType(BeanManager beanManager, Class<?> type) {
        return beanManager.getBeans(type).isEmpty();
    }

    private <T> Bean<T> defineBean(BeanManager beanManager, AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType) {
        BeanAttributes<T> beanAttributes = beanManager.createBeanAttributes(annotatedType);
        InjectionTargetFactory<T> injectionTargetFactory = beanManager.getInjectionTargetFactory(annotatedType);
        return beanManager.createBean(beanAttributes, annotatedType.getJavaClass(), injectionTargetFactory);
    }
}
```

An example of a default implementation of a service interface would be:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(SomeService.class)
public class SomeServiceDefaultImpl implements SomeService {

    @Override
    public String doSomeCalculation() {
        return "from default implementation";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Nikos, I think I did try something of this sorts as well, but didn't VETO the one with the "conditional" annotation, and therefore, ended up with that validation error before I could reach the afterBeanDiscovery phase. Bad mistake on my part, thanks a lot, Niko.

Comment: Specialization & Qualifiers can work, however, not exactly what I want- I want no specialized bean in the context if the same kind is already present. With @Specialization, I'm going to override existing with mine- doesn't serve the case- I'd like mine only to exist when there isn't any other[beyond my control- mine is a library].